# Matching two strings using Regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have two files, each contains a number on each line. Let's name them File A and File B. Each file contains roughly 2 million lines, and I'm trying to match those numbers using Regex.

The tricky part is that, each number in B can be a number in A + "00" or can simply be equal to A.

```
B = A OR B = A + "00"
```

This is how I'm identifying my Regex:

```
Regex re = new Regex("[0-9](0)*");
```

My code stores the smaller file into a HashSet, then I build my Regex and do the matching:

```
HashSet<string> matchVal = new HashSet<string>();

            foreach (var mdeSubid in File.ReadLines("FileA.txt"))
            {
                matchVal.Add(mdeSubid);
            }

            Regex re = new Regex("[0-9](0)*");
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("output.txt");

            foreach (var rx in File.ReadLines("FileB.txt"))
            {
                var matches = re.Matches(rx);
                foreach (Match m in matches)
                {
                    if (matchVal.Contains(m))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(m);   
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("DONE!");
            Console.ReadLine();
```

When I'm running my script I'm not getting any match even though I'm sure 100% that there are bunch of them.

Real Example

File A:

846535465

846536589

8465631

File B:

84653546500

846536589

846563100

846563102

In the example, B should match A in all cases except the last one,

```
846535465 == 84653546500
846536589 == 846536589 
8465631 == 846563100
8465631 != 846563101
```

Comment: m is a Match object.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Still no matches found

Comment: Can you show some examples of the actual contents of FileA and FileB? It's very difficult to determine where the problem is, without knowing exactly what you have as input and what you expect as output.

Comment: @LarsKristensen Example added

Comment: Are the numbers in order like this? Why are you using Regex?

Comment: @Enigmativity No the numbers are not in that order this is a sample of the files, each file has unique 2 million numbers at least and I need to find matches between the two files and print the matched number from B to a new file.
I'm using Regex because Numbers in File B could be either similar to Numbers in File A or similar to Numbers in File A + 00 "Two zeros".
So I'm doing Regex matching to deal with that case.

Comment: @WT86 - Do the files only contain numbers and are the numbers separated by spaces?

Comment: @WT86 - You're calling `File.ReadLines` so it appears that the numbers are on separate lines. Is the sample data you provided just showing spaces between them for the example or are the multiple numbers on each line?

Comment: @Enigmativity Numbers are on separate lines, I mldified the question

Comment: If every line starts with a sequence of numbers, followed by some sort of separator, just split the string on that separator and check the first element of the resulting array for a match in your hashset, no need to regex

Comment: @GeekJosh, That would be easy if `FileB` simply contained the same numbers as in `FileA`. The tricky part is that a number in `FileA` may or may not have two trailing zeroes in `FileB` (or it may not be present at all).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your regex. What you're asking for is a single number followed by as many zeroes as possible.

`[0-9]` - any number

`(0)` - a matching group containing the number zero as many times as possible `*`

I believe what you really want is to match only the first part of the sequence, excluding the trailing zeroes, against a predefined list of numbers. I also believe you should make sure this is at the start of the line only, just in case you get a match elsewhere on the line causing a false positive.

Therefore, your regex should be:
`^(\d+)(00)?`

`^` - asset position at the start of the string

`(\d+)` - first capture group, match any number one or more times

`(00)?` - second capture group, match '00' zero or one times

Finally, you need to alter your code so that rather than checking simply for a match, you are checking that Group(1) is a match (the sequence minus the trailing zeroes)

**EDIT**

So I tried this regex out on www.regex101.com and it's not quite right. I'm asking for the first capture group to match as many digits as possible, which by definition already encompasses the second capture group. I'd suggest using the first part of the regex `^\d+` and doing the trailing zero check in code. Although that'll potentially double the time taken checking all those matches, I'm struggling to think of a more efficient method right now...

Answer (score 0):

This is far from ideal, but I gave it a shot. It requires reading all the lines of FileA first which isn't ideal if there are millions of lines, but I can't figure out if there is a way around that, that wouldn't slow down the process tremendously.

Anyway, here's the commented code, which simply prints the matches to the console.

```
//Read all the lines from FileA
var FileAContents = File.ReadAllLines(PathFileA);

//Read FileB one line at a time, and compare with FileA to search for matches.
string line;
StreamReader file = new StreamReader(PathFileB);
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    //Start by finding all the possible matches, where the line from FileB starts with something that can be found in FileA.
    List<string> possibleMatches = FileAContents.Where(m => line.StartsWith(m)).ToList();
    foreach(string pm in possibleMatches)
    {
        //If the lines are completely equal, you've found a match.
        if(pm.Equals(line))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Match found, FileA: {0}, FileB: {1}", pm, line);
        }
        else if(line.EndsWith("00"))
        {
            //Remove the "00", then check if you've found a match.
            string tempLine = line.Substring(0, line.Length - 2);
            if(pm.Equals(tempLine))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Match found, FileA: {0}, FileB: {1}", pm, line);
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have here is that you're matching against a very large number of values. It is possible that you may run low on memory. Here are two possible choices of ways to go.

The first is the simplest, but may use too much memory:

```
var words = new HashSet<string>(
    File
        .ReadLines("FileA.txt")
        .SelectMany(x => new[] { x, x + "00" }));

var query = from word in File.ReadLines("FileB.txt")
            where words.Contains(word)
            select word;

File.WriteAllLines("output.txt", query);
```

The second uses a structure called a "trie" which can be far more efficient with the storage of the numbers from the first file. It depends on how random the numbers are.

```
void Main()
{
    var words = File.ReadLines("FileA.txt").SelectMany(x => new[] { x, x + "00" });

    var trie = new Trie(words);

    var query = from word in File.ReadLines("FileB.txt")
                where trie.Contains(word)
                select word;

    File.WriteAllLines("output.txt", query);
}

public class Trie : Dictionary<char, Trie>
{
    public Trie() : base(0) { }
    public Trie(IEnumerable<string> words) : base(0)
    {
        foreach (var word in words)
        {
            this.Add(word);
        }
    }

    public void Add(string word)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(word))
        {
            this[char.MinValue] = null;
        }
        else
        {
            Trie t = null;
            if (this.ContainsKey(word[0]))
            {
                t = this[word[0]];
            }
            else
            {
                t = new Trie();
                this[word[0]] = t;
            }
            t.Add(word.Substring(1));
        }
    }

    public bool Contains(string prefix)
    {
        return this.ContainsInternal(prefix + char.MinValue);
    }

    private bool ContainsInternal(string prefix)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix) && this.ContainsKey(prefix[0]))
        {
            return prefix.Length == 1 || this[prefix[0]].ContainsInternal(prefix.Substring(1));
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Both versions work in my tests.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code (it's using [System.Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.linq(v=vs.111).aspx)):

```
var fileA = new string[] {"846535465", "846536589", "8465631"};
var fileB = new string[] {"84653546500", "846536589", "846563100", "846563102"};

foreach (var bText in fileB){
    var aText = fileA.FirstOrDefault(a => Regex.Match(bText, ("^(" + a + ")(00)?$")).Success);
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(aText)){
        Console.WriteLine("B: " + bText + " - A: " + aText);
    }       
}
```

In this case, you check if the line in file B matches any value from file A, either with or without **00**.

In the above example, fileA and fileB arrays are your file contents, I just simplified them to be arrays, so you can test it quickly.

**EDIT:
This example may not be the best when it comes to performance, but you can get the idea from here, to build the Regex dynamically.**